# In this example, is boxing used when unboxing is needed?

Tags: java, c#, boxing, unboxing

I have some difficulty understanding the following part from [Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott](https://books.google.com/books?id=jM-cBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA233&ots=ysB-f7Vyh1&dq=C%23%20and%20more%20recent%20versions%20of%20Java%20perform%20automatic%20boxing%20and%20unboxing%20operations%20that%20avoid%20the%20wrapper%20syntax%20in%20many%20cases&pg=PA233#v=onepage&q=C%23%20and%20more%20recent%20versions%20of%20Java%20perform%20automatic%20boxing%20and%20unboxing%20operations%20that%20avoid%20the%20wrapper%20syntax%20in%20many%20cases&f=false)

> C# and more recent versions of Java perform automatic boxing and
>   unboxing operations that avoid
>   the wrapper syntax in many cases:
>
> ```
> ht.put(13, 31);
> int m = (Integer) ht.get(13);
> ```
>
> Here the Java compiler creates hidden Integer objects to hold the
>   values 13 and 31, so they may be passed to put as references. **The
>   Integer cast on the return value is still needed, to make sure that
>   the hash table entry for 13 is really an integer and not, say, a
>   ﬂoating-point number or string.** Generics, which we will consider in
>   Section 7.3.1, allow the programmer to declare a table containing only
>   integers. In Java, this would eliminate the need to cast the return
>   value. In C#, it would eliminate the need for boxing.

1. I was wondering what it means by "The Integer cast on the return
   value is still needed, to make sure that the hash table entry for 13
   is really an integer and not, say, a ﬂoating-point number or
   string"? Note that this is in Java.

   In `int m = (Integer) ht.get(13);`, does it use boxing (by
   `(Integer)`) during unboxing (assignment to `int`)?

   Specifically, does  `(integer)` convert its operand to an object of
   the `Integer` class? But its operand  `ht.get(13)`  is already an
   `Integer` object, and now the assignment expects a value of builtin
   type `int`. So don't we need a conversion from `Integer` to `int` 
   here?
2. How does generics "eliminate the need to cast the return value" in
   Java ?

   In C#, how would it "eliminate the need for boxing"?

Thanks.

Comment: `Hashtable#get` has a return type of `Object` in that example. That comment is unrelated to the boxing.

Comment: Thanks. Why is `(Integer)` applied to its return, if its return is already `Integer`?

Comment: The (Integer) cast is quite confusing in a generics world, but the idea here is to cast the raw return type (Object) into (Integer) and THEN unboxing into (int) happens.

Comment: So the _value_ returned might be a reference to an `Integer`, but the compile time type of the expression `ht.get(..)` is `Object`. `Object` is not convertible to an `int` through an assignment expression, you need the cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Without specifying generic types on the declaration of `ht`, the return type of `get()` is `Object`, so you have to cast that to `Integer`. Java will then auto-unbox that to `int`.

   The cast itself doesn't do any conversion. It just tells the compiler to treat the `Object` as an `Integer`. If the object is not in fact an `Integer`, a `ClassCastException` will occur at runtime.
2. With use of generic types, `ht` would likely be declared as `Map<Integer, Integer>`, so `get()` would return `Integer`, and cast would be redundant.

   In C#, it could be declared as the Java equivalent of `Map<int, int>`. Java doesn't support *primitive* types as generic type arguments, so that syntax would be illegal.